# alternative for find_task_by_pid()

Tags: linux, unix, pid, system-calls

I need to access task with given **pid** in my syscall. Apparently function **find_task_by_pid()** was serving this purpose in older versions of Linux kernel. It seems like only function to search for task with given pid available in newer kernels (like 3.13) is find_task_by_vpid() . Would calling this function return same task as previous one for given pid? *( What does virtual ( local ) PID mean ? )* If not, is there function equivalent to find_task_by_id() ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me :

pid_task(find_vpid(arg1), PIDTYPE_PID)

where arg1 is variable of type pid_t